# Missing / lost final Lensmen book?

Tags: history-of, lensman-series

The tumblr feed [Vintage Geek Culture](https://vintagegeekculture.tumblr.com/post/675512338906071040/the-pulp-scifi-lost-media-holy-grail) claims that there's one more Lensmen novel out there, which was too...much to be published back in the day.

> Somewhere, in the hands of the Jeannie and Clarissa MacDougal-Smith
> Estate in Clearwater, Florida, there is a yellowed, dusty manuscript
> that is the finale and final chapter of the most ambitious science
> fiction series of all time, which remains totally unseen and
> unpublished, because it was too incendiary for the morals of the
> Victorian public of the 1940s.
>
> I’m talking about E.E. Smith’s Lensman space opera series. The
> first massive, ambitious space opera series written over several
> books, the Lensman novels are huge books of apocalyptically massive
> grandeur. Their biggest contribution to popular culture is the visual
> of space marines in power armor, which dates back to his Valerians,
> giants raised on a hostile high-gravity world. But Lensman was filled
> with tremendous imagery. His stories have things like the
> Ultra-Spacial Tube, which transports an armada of millions of
> starships of Galactic Civilization from one galaxy to another…if they
> survive. The mental battles in this series have parried mind blows
> that end up killing hundreds of bystanders. There is Helmuth, Speaker
> for Boskone, a pirate leader and supreme strategist with glowing blue
> skin who may be one of the most terrifying, strategic, and
> intellectual villains in science fiction. The Hell Hole in Space, from
> which no living thing ever returns. Creatures like the dragon-like
> Velantians, the torture chambers of the Overlords of Delgon, and the
> supremely demonic Eich, malevolent geniuses who breathe freezing
> poison gases. The finale involved millions of Lensmen all over the
> galaxy activating their lens devices to merge their minds into a
> single supreme mentality for a final battle.

Heinlein claimed to have read it, agreeing that it couldn't have been published at the time.

Being a big fan of the series, I was shocked to have never heard of this.  I'd love to believe it was true, but I wonder if it's as apocryphal (in the details, at least) as David McDaniel's last **Man from U.N.C.L.E.** novel, *The Final Affair*.

Anyone else heard of this?

Comment: "*The Lensman [series] was left unfinished. There was to have been at least a seventh volume. As always, **Doc had worked it out in great detail, but never (so far as I know) wrote it down ... because it was unpublishable** —then. But he told me the ending orally and in private...  Possibly somewhere there is a manuscript—..."* ~ Heinlein

Comment: Heinlein most certainly did not claim to have read it

Comment: It's pretty obvious that the Children of the Lens would have mated with each other. So, eww.

Answer (score 5):

Valorum's quote in the comment is from [Heinlein's "Expanded Universe,"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expanded_Universe_(book)) in the essay "Larger Than Life."  The more complete quote from my copy of the book:

> The Lensman novel was left unfinished; there was to have been at least
> a seventh volume. As always, Doc had worked it out in great detail,
> but never (so far as I know) wrote it down ... because it was
> unpublishable —then. But he told me the ending orally and in private.
>
> I shan't repeat it; it is not my story. Possibly somewhere there is a
> manuscript—I *hope* so.  All I will say is that the ending develops by
> inescapable logic from clues in CHILDREN OF THE LENS.

I remember reading this and thinking, like Organic Marble's comment, that unpublishable part was probably the Kinnison siblings hooking up in some (or all?) combinations.

I don't have my Lensman books handy, but I recall that some or all of the Children of the Lens think to themselves how much better their siblings are than any other human they've ever met - stronger, smarter, tougher, better looking...

Comment: One example - in Chapter 16 Karen, thinking about her brother  "All other men were lumps. Kit was so far ahead of any other man in existence that there was simply no comparison."

Comment: I can absolutely agree that this direction would be squicky, even today. I'm trying to recall the story (Not gladiator, though it may have been a comic book adaptation of it) Where a similarly advanced/evolved human realizes he has no more interest in breeding with ordinary humans. The Children may well feel that way, but I'd rather not seen them go the other route.

Comment: Interesting. Judging from his own novels, Heinlein saw nothing squicky in incest and would have been a sympathetic ear for E. E. Smith.